# Which Responsive web app framework to use

Tags: web-apps

Question for the community!

I have only been a developer for about 6 months and it's more a hobby than anything else. I have a full time job at a mom and pop HVAC company and was thinking of creating my first big project and using it to help the company in the process. I have started building out the web app pretty much with just basic html css, and js, but with it being more of an app and less of a website, I am wondering if maybe a framework like react or svelte would be more of the route I want to take.

If anyone would be so kind as to take a look at what I have so far and get an idea of the project (it's pretty self explanatory from what's on the site right now) and give me some feedback on what your thoughts are on the best framework to start looking into...

The site url for now is: comfort-solutions.app

Most things are already styled responsively with bootstrap, and I would like to use bootstrap regardless of any other framework I use.

I really want it to have the feel of an app and not just a site. Also, in your recommendations, please give feedback on the difficulty of reusing what work I have put in so far if I switched gears at this point.

Thank you to all who read this.

PS:  I am aware that the color tones are not "pretty"  Trust me they definitely weren't my 1st choice, but the owner of the company is not really Tech savvy and in order to gain his attention up front I wanted to design it similar to an older desktop app that they currently use.    Hoping that when he gives me the green light to actually put the app in production after it has been completely finished that evil let me adjust to a more robust styling